# Inserting rows in form datasource, insert is OK, rows are not visible

Tags: forms, insert, datasource, axapta, x++

Basically, I want to insert rows in the form InventJournalTransfer. I added a menuitem button that calls a class which opens a dialog where I fill a WMSLocationId, then I loop on Inventsum table to get all ItemIds with Available qty for this WMSLocationId and insert them into InventJournalTrans Table.

The code I wrote seems to be working as I have correct records inserted in my table(visible in Table browser, correct journalId, linenum itemId, qty etc...) BUT the records inserted do not appear in my form. I tried to refresh my form with or without code, but my grid's still empty.

I had a look at the class InventCountCreate that does what I want to do in a different journal type, but as I'm quite a newbie it is difficult for me to understand exactly how this class works.

Could anyone explain to me how to display my inserted rows in my form or give other leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InventJournalTrans` is table is inner joined to two `InventDim`, one related via the `InventDimId` field, the other via `ToInventDimId`.

Both fields must be filled with a valid `InventDimId` to an existing `InventDim` record for the form to show the record.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking on your form's node in the AOT and clicking "Restore"? Perhaps your form is still using cached data.